# insert into table on duplicate key update with backup

Tags: mysql

I want to backup data into another table which is updating without trigger/procedure like

insert into table1 ('value1','value2') on duplicate key insert into table2 value( oldvalue1, oldvalue2) update value1, value2

how this can be possible? I don't have permission to create trigger/procedure in mysql

Comment: Could you please provide a litle more information. What do you mean with duplicate key? When get you a duplicated key?

Comment: Perform `SELECT` on key on `table1`. If match, `INSERT` into `table2`, then `UPDATE` on `table1`. If no match, `INSERT` into `table1`?

Comment: @ShambhulalVerma Hi, friend, how can I contact you? I have a question to ask you.